# The problem with currently running directory in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I know, this is an old story, but is there any decent way to make production project's directory as currently running directory in IntelliJ IDEA, so that I can read local files located in the same directory with reading class by their relative paths?

Assume, there are two files in my project's `src` directory 
(`C:\projects\Test1\src\`):

```
- ReaderClass.java
- properties.xml
```

When project is compiled and built, the output is moved to `production` directory (`C:\projects\Test1\out\production\Test1\`):

```
- ReaderClass.class
- properties.xml
```

However, if my `ReaderClass` contains some code such as:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("properties.xml"))) {
    props.loadFromXML(is);
    ...
}
```

I get the error: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: properties.xml`

The problem is that, while debugging the class from IntelliJ IDEA, both `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()` refer to 
`C:\projects\Test1\` as the currently running directory.

So, to get the "real" production currently running directory, I have to decorate my code with workarounds like this:

```java
try {
    URI currentRelativeURI = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getResource("").toURI();
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get(currentRelativeURI);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    ... 
}
```

or as in this particular example I could get the `InputStream` by calling `MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getResourceAsStream("properties.xml")`.

This is a bit annoying, since I could simply use `Paths.get("")` and `Paths.get("properties.xml")` to refer to the local files by their relative paths in 
production code without the need to handle all those URI's URISyntaxExceptions just for the debugging purposes.

Alternative solution is to move temporarily all local files out of the `src` into `C:\projects\Test1\`, and return them back after debugging... but this is also a bit inconvenient, to say the least.

Comment: Resources are not files. You should be using `getResource()` and friends.

Comment: Thank you. It's my fault, I used wrong terminology mixing files and resources, but the question is still the same as far as reading local files by their relative paths is concerned.

Comment: Is `currently running directory` your way of naming `current working directory`?

Comment: You should *still* be using `getResource()` and friends, and not using `File` or `FileInputStream` and friends at all. You can't rely in any way on what's in your `src` directory ending up in the current working directory when you execute your application. And you don't need to.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, currently working directory and currently running directory in my question have the same meaning. It's where I expect Paths.get("") refer to.

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory is absolutely unrelated with the currently running class and can be basically anything you want when you run a Java program. The root of your project is just what IDEA chooses by default if you don't specify something in your run configuration.

You have various options:

1. define what your application expects the current working directory to be (i.e. what files need to be in there), make sure that all the ways you execute your application set this up correctly and use relative paths to find your resources
2. don't use the current working directory, but provide a configuration or parameter to your application that tells it where to find its resources (something like passing a directory name to your `main` method for example). This one is very similar to #1 but instead of using the current working directory implicitly you make the base path explicit.
3. bundle all the required files in your jars and use the resource loading mechanisms to load them (again, using relative paths, but in this case the resources might not be "files" in the traditional sense, if they are packed in a jar file).

Which of these to pick, depends on your exact requirements. For data files that are fixed, #3 is usually the best choice, as it's the most robust (no need to have the correct working directory or pass the right arguments). If the end user should be able to modify the resource files (or provide their own), then one of the other two options are better suited.